# Not able to create ionic project after Visual studio installation

Tags: ionic2

ionic start myApp tabs

Creating Ionic app in folder C:\Users\Swanandi\myAquire based on tabs project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Error with start Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Swanandi\android-sdks\tools\ionic-starter-1476779357812.zip'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1333:33)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\utils.js:121:10)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:373:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request. (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:1318:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
Error Initializing app: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Swanandi\android-sdks\tools\ionic-starter-1476779357812.zip'
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Swanandi\android-sdks\tools\ionic-starter-1476779357812.zip'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1333:33)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\utils.js:121:10)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:373:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request. (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:1318:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
Caught exception:
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Swanandi\android-sdks\tools\ionic-starter-1476779357812.zip'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1333:33)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\utils.js:121:10)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:373:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request. (C:\Users\Swanandi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:1318:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed